# Passing options to fancybox v2 with the $.fancybox() syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm doing something fairly custom with `Fancybox` and I'm passing it a set of new images to use.

```
$.fancybox(galleryList); // This works
```

Where **galleryList** is an array of image objects.

Thing is, I also have to pass it a custom index option.

```
$(galleryList).fancybox({ // This does not work
    index : imgIndex
});
```

Where **imgIndex** is a non-negative integer.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
$.fancybox(galleryList, {
    index: imgIndex 
});
```